# MySQL database transfer from server to client

Tags: php, mysql, client, data-transfer

I want to transfer my one machine database to another machine.

Whenever in my one machine(server) data is generated it must be transferred to another machine.

But if I delete data from my server the changes should not imply on the other machine.

Only insertion from server to client should be allowed no deletion from server to client should imply changes.

Answer (score 2):

You should read some doc about [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html). Put some on INSERT and UPDATE events on the tables you need to backup.